# i have exported a code form code pen but not working

Tags: codepen

code pen code exported for local development, but not working and redirecting to
https://greensock.com/requires-membership/?plugin=SplitText&source=codepen

how to make it work and utilize the code. Any help will be highly appreciated
codepen.io/jaymierosen/pen/mBzyLR
this is the code i want to work on...

Comment: seems pretty clear to me, you need a membership in Greensock for it to work

Comment: its no always required to be member for everything, my concern to ask was is their any other way i can get the code working...

https://codepen.io/jaymierosen/pen/mBzyLR this is the code i want to work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow all the steps here https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/exporting-pens/

If it doesn't work, could you post all the steps that you are doing to get to where this breaks.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jaymierosen/pen/mBzyLR this is the code i want to work on...

Comment: ohh, I see. You just need membership for greensock. You can't use their features if you download, only if you work on codepen.io. I forked and removed the greensock dependencies, now you can see index.html in the browser.

Comment: sure, you can export from here. It just doesn't have any greensock dependencies https://codepen.io/spicymaya/pen/VwwaqzY